# D3 Plotting Rectangles from Coordinate data

Tags: d3.js, svg

I have rectangles that I would like to plot from a csv file in the following format:

```
x1,x2,y1,y2,color
2,4,5,8,blue
4,7,9,11,red
...
```

So basically, I have the endpoints for each rectangle, however conventional D3 appends rects using `x`, `y`, `height` and `width` -- all of which are needed I believe. `x1`, `x2`, `y1`, `y2` don't apply to rects if I'm not mistaken. So I'm a little confused about which approach to take.

I originally thought a line or path could do the trick, but I do not think I can create distinct shapes and distinct fills this way, as they would all be drawn in one fell swoop.

Please advise as to which methods would be most suitable for this data type.

Comment: you can calculate x, y, width and height from x1, y1, y1, y2 though can't you?

Comment: @RobertLongson I suppose I could, I can't think outside the box :(. I guess I'll do it that way. If there is some other elegant way, then I'll leave this question as is.

Comment: @ArashHowaida *"Elegant"* is something primarily opinion-based. I think you're asking for a *working way*, whatever that way is...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `width` is just `x2 - x1` and `height` is just `y2 - y1`:

```
rectangleSelection.attr("x", function(d) {
        return d.x1
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
        return d.y1
    })
    .attr("width", function(d) {
        return d.x2 - d.x1
    })
    .attr("height", function(d) {
        return d.y2 - d.y1
    })
    .attr("fill", function(d) {
        return d.color
    })
```

Here is a demo (I'm using a `<pre>` element to simulate your CSV, and also I'm increasing your values for better see the rectangles):

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");

var data = d3.csvParse(d3.select("#csv").text())

var rects = svg.selectAll("foo")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("rect");

rects.attr("x", function(d) {
    return d.x1
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return d.y1
  })
  .attr("width", function(d) {
    return d.x2 - d.x1
  })
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return d.y2 - d.y1
  })
  .attr("fill", function(d) {
    return d.color
  })
```

```css
pre{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<pre id="csv">x1,x2,y1,y2,color
20,40,50,80,blue
40,70,90,110,red
70,130,60,80,green</pre>
<svg></svg>
```

Have in mind that you have to be sure that `y2` is greater than `y1` and `x2` is greater than `x1`. Otherwise you'll get an error: `A negative value is not valid.`

Comment: I believe `d.y2` is what we want, that makes the plot anchor correctly. I tried `d.y1` which resulted in overlaps and missing gaps . Also I believe `Math.abs()` for width/height can make the plot robust to domains that have negative values. Still I know you did your best, not to mention you didn't have access to my dataset.